# Setting xml value in powershell failing with Property '...' cannot be found on this object

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to load a csproj file and change it's root namespace in powershell.

The xml of the csproj file looks like:

```
<Project...xmlsns="   >
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RootNamespace>SomeNamespace</RootNamespace>
```

...

I can get the value, navigating by property

```
> $xmlDoc = (Get-Content myProject.csproj)

> $xmlDoc.Project.PropertyGroup.RootNamespace ## Outputs SomeNamespace
```

But i can't assign to it  - Setting xml value in powershell failing with Property '...' cannot be found on this object...

I have tried it with a handcrafted xml file and succeeded

```
<Test>
   <TestInner1>
      <TestInner2>SomeValue</TestInner2>
   </TestInner1>
</Test>

>$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content test.xml)
>$xmlDoc.Test.TestInner1.TestInner2 = "Some Other Value"
>$xmlDoc.Test.TestInner1.TestInner2 ## Returns Some Other Value
```

I have modified the elements under TestInner2 - added additional elements, self closed elements. I've added a namespace to Test. Still able to set the value in each of these cases.

When in the powershell ISE, getting intellisense for the types I note that in my test xml each of Test, TestInner1 and TestInner2 are all XmlElements. However on the project file Project and PropertyGroup are XmlElements - but then the Intellisense stops and doesn't provide RootNamespace. When i get the type of PropertyGroup it's an Object[], and of RootNamespace is string. RootNamespace claims to have be { get; set; } but i get the aforementioned error on setting.

If there is a workaround that works on the project file I'm interested, but I'm equally interested to know why the two examples above differ i.e what am i missing !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is more than one **PropertyGroup** node under **Project** node. Usually.

XmlDocument class will return first element if there is only one, but if there is more it will require an index. Your **Test** example works because there is only one sub element with name **TestInner2**. If you know the position of the **PropertyGroup** element you can access it by index

```
$xmlDoc.Project.PropertyGroup[0].RootNamespace
```

Or you use the Force to bend xml to your will

```
($xmlDoc.Project.PropertyGroup | Where-Object { $_['RootNamespace'] -ne $null}).RootNamespace = "new value"
```

Comment: Can't believe i didn't try that ! In my defence the other PropertyGroup elements were at the end of the csproj file (a pretty flimsy defence !). And awesomely you've not just corrected my how to navigate to that property but how to neatly set it. Thanks !!

Comment: Saved me some headache after playing with this for a few minutes....  duh... multiple propertygroup sections.... :-)

Comment: Man, men, my men! Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

This one also can work

```
$propertyGroupNode = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Project/PropertyGroup")
$propertyGroupNode.RootNamespace = "new value"
```